# Is the "=" operator overloaded for msg variables?

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was worrying whether the "=" operator is systematically overloaded for objects of class sensor_msgs::JointState and other predefined messages in ROS. Up to now, I have programmed that "by hand" but it's a bit silly if the = operator is enough. That said, I do not know how to check that.

If it is the case for predefined messages, then is it also true when one defines their own message types (which I never had to do up to now, I must admit).

Thanks for any input.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163276/is-the-%22=%22-operator-overloaded-for-msg-variables?/) by [ggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/15026/ggg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 2

---

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no need to overload the operator. Everything in messages is stored as values, so copy, assignment, etc. work as expected.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. ROS message types have an `operator=` in C++.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1